# Changing the keys of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, key

Say I have these :

```
$services = array();
$services["services0"];
$services["services1"];
$services["services2"];
$services["services3"];
```

And I would like to create some kind of loop to change these to:

```
$services[0];
$services[1];
$services[2];
$services[3];
```

How would you go about doing so? Not knowing how many key : value pair you have in an array?

Comment: Yes, there are two nice ways... using a `for` or `foreach` loop.

Comment: I understand both concept ... but I was thinking, maybe I first get the amounts of element withing the array, Then create for loop starting at zero until the length of the array. Inside that loop create a foreach loop that goes into each `$key` and replace that with the current iteration ...

Comment: I'm sure there must be an easier to get around this issue !?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this and discard the original keys is to just run the array through [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$new_array = array_values( $old_array);
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/5JWiKz) that the following example:

```
$services = array();
$services["services0"] = 's0';
$services["services1"] = 's1';
$services["services2"] = 's2';
$services["services3"] = 's3';

$services = array_values( $services);

print_r( $services);
```

Produces this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => s0
    [1] => s1
    [2] => s2
    [3] => s3
)
```

Comment: ... unless if it isn't actually sorted by key, you need [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Comment: Amazing ! Thanks for this amazing one liner, I never heard of before :) I love Stackoverflow and sharing with you guys... We learn new things everyday !

Comment: Just a note: It only *looks* like the numbers in the keys (i.e. 0-3) are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following code:

```
$dummy_array = $services;
$services = array();
foreach($dummy_array as $service) {
    $services[] = $service;

}
```

What is happening here is that you are unsetting services (but saving it first) Then you loop through your saved version adding the values back into an array. The line `$services[] = $service;` is key here. This appends a value to the end of an existing array with a standard key. ie 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on. This creates the result that you want of removing the string keys and replacing them with standard array key indecies. Try it out and see what you get. Good luck

Comment: Very cool I will that in mind, I'd like to thank you for your contribution, You code is simple and neat and does what expected, however the code above is a one liner and also a neat little function i never seen before so the point goes out to him but I do like your function too

Comment: @hayonj No problem. I use the array[] syntax a lot in my work. It comes in handy for other types of problems so its a good tool to have in your kit. I'm not sure why others are down voting a valid solution though. Strange place this is I guess...

Comment: Your answer is as valid as the one above i wish i could help you not to get a vote down. I don't know how to proceed but your code works and shouldn't be voted down and could be use for many other things other than what i needed it for

Comment: @hayonj if you find my answer useful, up votes always help. Catch you later dude.

Comment: require 15 reputation  :) as soon as I get there i'll upvote ! i'm at 10 now

Comment: besides I like you way of explaning the function as most people over don't really get into details that much ... they paste in a function without explaning it too much ...